# Can this be viewed as an I/O bound task?

Tags: multithreading, io, multiprocessing, cpu

Let's say you have 4 physical cores on your computer, and let's assume there is no hyperthreading and that python version is 3.2+ (although I am not sure if these extra information matter for my question).

If I were to open a pool of 3 subprocesses, hence each subprocess occupying one physical core when they do some CPU bound tasks, and if I were to open up 3 threads from the current process (occupying one core left from 4) where the OS is running, and if I were to send CPU bound tasks down the multiprocessing to each of the 3 subprocesses, then the question is this:

From the perspective of the current process that is managing the threads (and these threads are pushing tasks out to each subprocesses and is waiting for the result to come back from these subprocesses), can these CPU bound tasks be viewed as I/O bound tasks (from the perspective of current process) since the current process is not actually doing any work? Equivalently, will the 3 threads go to sleep, while the 3 subprocesses are crunching away at the numbers and occupying the 3 cores, and let the last core sit there idling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will the 3 threads go to sleep, while the 3 subprocesses are crunching away at the numbers and occupying the 3 cores, and let the last core sit there idling?

Yes. I can't imagine what else could happen, do you have another possibility in mind? As you say, the threads are waiting.

In this situation you can probably make 4 processes to work on the CPU bound tasks.

It sounds like your problem is well suited for [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool). In that case note that if you don't specify the number of processes to use, it uses the number of CPU cores by default:

> *processes* is the number of worker processes to use. If *processes* is `None` then the number returned by `os.cpu_count()` is used.

which is an official sign that using as many processes as cores is a normal practice.

Comment: The use case I have in mind is I have multiple computers, one master and 9 (for example) slaves, and each have 4 (for ex) CPU cores. There is one master process in the master computer assigning tasks to a subprocess pegged to each CPU cores in both master computer and all the slave computers

Comment: So I would have 9 X 4 (from slave comp) + 3 (from master node) available CPU cores to do work. And the last process will be left to do assigning of works by opening up 39 threads (or hundreds depending on the configurations)

Comment: But since these works can be regarded as I/O bound tasks, I feel free to opening up as many threads as I want to... the GIL will be passed around among these threads in the main process and I wouldn't have too much overhead

Comment: @Jay sounds like your master already has plenty of work to do and using all of its cores on CPU bound (and perhaps memory intensive) work isn't the best idea, especially since it will only increase available CPU cores by a small percentage. But ultimately the only way to know is to measure.

Comment: is "using all of its cores on CPU bound (and perhaps memory intensive) work isn't the best idea" bound to master node? because you said "In this situation you can probably make 4 processes to work on the CPU bound tasks." But "specially since it will only increase available CPU cores by a small percentage" sounds like something that applies in general and not just master?

Comment: I do plan to leave 1 CPU physical core out from each slave node and 2 CPU physical cores from the master (1 to do threading, 1 to do intercomputer communications etc). Do you have any rule of thumb in mind that one can follow as an initial prior?

Comment: @Jay use all the cores on the slaves, not doing so would reduce your available cores by 25%. Maybe don't use all the cores in the master, each core there is just 2.5%. In fact consider not doing any CPU work on the master at all. Using it will probably make your code more complicated and make it harder to match costs to resource usage. If you can choose the hardware, just make sure the master has enough memory and bandwidth and don't spend money on CPU when some of that will be wasted.

Comment: That's a fair point. The thing is, to tell you the full details, I am forced to open master that has same configurations as the slaves, and each of the nodes can contain up to 32 cores. So when I just use the slaves (and for a long time), like 30 cores are sitting idling in master, and I want to squeeze these too since I'm paying for these as well... is this a good reason to do what I am trying to do? Or do you still think I should not use any CPU cores in master?

Comment: I guess this decision depends on empirical measurements as you said. Perhaps it's not a good idea to ask for a general guidance on such a matter. This was very helpful thanks!

Comment: @Jay in that case I would use the master, it sounds like quite a waste of money otherwise.